# C# String.Compare in FirstOrDefault from entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable, string-comparison

I'm loosing it... =\

Using .NET Framework 4
Using entity framework to get to MS SQL DB

(JFYI - Here is some ugly looking code. As it is for a local service and won't ever be working with tables larger than ~1000 rows - the tool set chose is more or less acceptable.)

Running the next code

```
var itemOfInterest = entity.tbl_Items
                           .FirstOrDefault(item => 
                                string.Compare(item.Name, SomeLocalItem.Name, true) == 0 
                            && (string.Compare(item.tbl_Server.FQDN, SomeLocalItem.ServerFQDN, true) == 0) 
                            || (string.Compare(item.Server.FQDN, WithoutDomainLocalFQDN, true) == 0)
                            );
```

and it returns me the first (or null) item, found just by the

```
    (string.Compare(item.tbl_Server.FQDN, SomeLocalItem.ServerFQDN, true) == 0)
 || (string.Compare(item.Server.FQDN, WithoutDomainLocalFQDN, true) == 0)
```

cause

When running

```
var serviceOfInterest = entity.tbl_Service
                              .Where(item => string.Compare(item.Name, SomeLocalItem.Name, true) == 0)
                              .FirstOrDefault(item => 
                                   (string.Compare(item.tbl_Server.FQDN, SomeLocalItem.ServerFQDN, true) == 0) 
                                || (string.Compare(item.Server.FQDN, WithoutDomainLocalFQDN, true) == 0)
                               );
```

I'm getting the correct result.

I don't feel well. May be the issue here is really simple, but I can't just see it. 
The strings compared in item Names look somehow like this:

"My Awesome Item - pen."

"My Awesome Item - Grand-pas gun"

"My Awesome Item - something in my pocket - for you"

Any help appreciated. I'm even OK with calling me names for such question, but I really really really need the answer.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using string.Compare == 0 to check for equality? I believe comparing strings with the == operator is better understood by Entity Framework because it allows the framework to build queries by analyzing the expression tree object created from the lambda.
Operator precedence may also be the issue. If the first query is evaluating as (a && b) || c it will not return the same results as the last query which is effectively a && (b || c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var itemOfInterest = entity.tbl_Items.FirstOrDefault(item => string.Compare(item.Name, SomeLocalItem.Name, true) == 0 && ((string.Compare(item.tbl_Server.FQDN, SomeLocalItem.ServerFQDN, true) == 0) || (string.Compare(item.Server.FQDN, WithoutDomainLocalFQDN, true) == 0)));
```

Comment: You got to be kidding me... 
Thanks!
Sorry folks for the stupid question. I don't mind if it will be deleted by administrators.